# Cohomology of a cochain complex of acyclic sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Ok, sort of as a follow up to my previous question, let's recall the de Rham-Weil theorem:
Let $F$ be a sheaf on a topological space $X$ and let $\mathcal{L}^{\bullet}$ be an acyclic resolution of $F$. Then $H^{q}(X,\mathcal{F}) \cong H^{q}(\mathcal{L}^{\bullet}({X}))$.

Now let's say I want to compute the cohomology of the complex $\mathcal{L}^{\bullet}({X})$ but my cochain complex

$0\rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{1} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{2} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{3}  \cdots $

is not exact, i.e. $\mathcal{L}^{\bullet}$ is not a resolution of $\mathcal{F}$. In my problem (the problem I'm working on) the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and all the sheaves $\mathcal{L}^{q}$ are acyclic. How do I go about solving computing the cohomology of $\mathcal{L}^{\bullet}({X})$? I'm a little bit lost here, any tips, ideas or techniques as to how to proceed?

Comment: Can you be more specific  about the complex $\mathcal{L}^\bullet$?   The answer depends on the differentials. If all the differential are zero the answer is the complex itself.    For other differentials you can expect a different answer.

Comment: That's all the information I have, it's a complex of acyclic sheaves, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the assumed acyclicity, what you are computing is the hypercohomology of the complex ${\cal L}^*$.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Steven Landsburg's answer, you have a spectral sequence
$$E_2^{pq}= H^p(X,\mathcal{H}^q(\mathcal{L}^\bullet)) \Rightarrow 
\mathbb{H}^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{L}^\bullet)$$
where the thing on the right is hypercohomology, i.e. the group you're after, and
$$\mathcal{H}^q(\mathcal{L}^\bullet) =\ker[\mathcal{L}^q\to \mathcal{L}^{q+1}]/image(\ldots)$$
are the cohomology sheaves. This should get you started. Also keep in mind that 
$\mathcal{H}^0(\mathcal{L}^\bullet)=\mathcal{F}$ assuming exactness at the first step.